# Groups whose non-linear irreducible characters are all non-faithful

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am interested in knowing if there is any literature that describes finite solvable groups whose non-linear complex irreducible characters are all non-faithful.

Comment: One reference is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01343.pdf.

Comment: what's a "non-linear" character?

Comment: @YCor, character of a non-1-dimensional representation.

Comment: @RichardStanley, I took the question to be about faithful _characters_ (meaning injective?).  Is that the same as characters of faithful _representations_?

Comment: @LSpice: A (complex) character is usually called faithful if the associated representations are faithful which is equivalent to $\chi(g)=\chi(1) \implies g=1$

Comment: OK; If $G$ is non-abelian the 1-dimensional characters are non-faithful, so the question is about non-abelian groups all of whose characters are non-faithful (but the restriction to non-abelian is artificial).

Answer (score 9):

A necessary and sufficient condition for a finite group $G$ to have a faithful complex irreducible character is given by a Theorem of W. Gaschutz, which states that a finite group $G$ has a faithful irreducible complex character if and only if the socle $S$ of $G$ is generated by the $G$-conjugates of a single element of $S$. Here, the socle of $G$ is the product of all minimal normal subgroups of $G$.

If $G$ is solvable, then all minimal normal subgroups are Abelian of prime-power order, and the socle of $G$ is Abelian of square-free exponent. Note that a non-Abelian solvable group $G$ has no faithful linear character. Hence a non-Abelian solvable group $G$ has no faithful (non-linear) complex irreducible character if and only if its socle $S$ can not be generated by the $G$-conjugates of any single element of $S$.

Comment: An extension characterizing countable discrete groups $G$ having a faithful irreducible unitary representation, can be found in Corollary 1.9 of PE Caprace, P. de la Harpe, "*Groups with irreducibly unfaithful subsets for unitary representations*". The condition is that finite normal subgroups of $G$ satisfy a certain property (and in particular is satisfied if there is no nontrivial abelian finite normal subgroup). See [on  arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.04992).

Comment: Thank you, I have something to work with.